# How to calculate Quartiles in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, statistics

I want to calculate mean,min,max,stddev, 25%,50%,75% values for the data in the spark data frame.
I have tried Summary() function but it does not give the exact values of 25%,50% and 75%... the values change in every run even if the data is same.

How to calculate exact 25%,50% and 75% along with other statistics?

Answer (score 1):

`Dataset.summary` uses `ApproximatePercentile` to compute the quartiles. If you need exact quartile use [percentile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) as below-

```scala
> SELECT percentile(col, 0.3) FROM VALUES (0), (10) AS tab(col);
 3.0
> SELECT percentile(col, array(0.25, 0.75)) FROM VALUES (0), (10) AS tab(col);
 [2.5,7.5]
```

Comment: If you check the documentation link for the function they clearly said the function `Returns the exact percentile value of numeric column col at the given percentage.`. Please observe numeric column